# Are 1H 2018 OSS ads showing up?

Tags: bug, advertising

Click [stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/362773) for the 1H 2018 [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) campaign are unusually low (to say the least), across the board.

Contrast against the [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/349017) and [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/327559) figures, is rather stark. It looks like the only clicks any 2018 ads ever got, came from the community ads post itself.

Something's up.

Comment: I've been trying to divide the  number of times I saw a CrossOver ad by the number of times I saw a community ad lately.  That's been coming up with DivideByZeroException for a while.

Comment: Crossover ads behave like _cancer_ cells - even if dormant, they keep growing and multiplying.

Comment: @pnuts lots of people use ad blockers, yes. Lots more don't, and with the traffic SO gets it is inevitable that a community ad gets *at least* a couple hundred clicks in the span of half a year. The current stats simply haven't moved at all since the last time I checked them at some point in February. My conclusion is that SO is only serving their paying customer ads, and OSS projects aren't getting any of the exposure they were supposed to be getting.

Comment: Digging in now. You may have found a stinker on this one. The OSS ads for the rest of our sites seem to be running fine, but I'm not seeing anything for SO. Should have this resolved soon and will post an update below.

Comment: @stevvve is there an update on what's happened here?

Comment: @Vogel612 Digging around now. The code used to generate these dynamically is... old. And built for another system. Just trying not to break things!

Comment: @stevvve my sympathies! OTOH, *it's already broken*, so... what could possibly go wrong? ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon <homer_into_hedge.gif>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, yeah. Those were off. Unfortunately, there's no getting that back. However, you caught it in time to get *some* delivery for the 1H ads, and we'll be all set for 2H.

The ads should start seeing delivery soon, though it takes a little while for reporting on my end to populate. I'll keep an eye on it for a while to ensure things are delivering as intended.

Any updates will be shared here.

Thank you for spotting this!

Comment: Did you write a unit test and/or report to make sure this stops happening?

Comment: Having a "times served" metric on each OSS add would definitely help I think.

Comment: @Hosch250 Come on, nobody write unit tests, they're like unicorns and rocking horse droppings - purely mythical.

Comment: @DavidG .......

Comment: @TestCoverageUnicorn You can change your name all you like, but you'll always be `battery.cord` to me...

Comment: Hey stevvve, are we totally completely sure it's fixed? I still haven't seen any of them yet.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Given the *massive* amount of impressions served on a monthly basis, the likelihood that you'll see one specific ad, especially one with a smaller share of voice, is remote. The open source ads received about 150,000 impressions since my last update, and I expect that number to steadily increase over time.

Comment: Since you're "all set for 2H", is the 2H 2018 ad campaign planned for soon?